# Ionic framework: The first item in Ionic list is disappeared

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic world.  I ran into an issue.  I was following the direction from ionic web site with contents. However, somehow the first item on the list is not showing at all.  Could any of you help?  Thanks a lot. Here is my code:

And also why my ion-tabs automatically appears in the footer area? If I want it to appear on the top can I?

```
<div class="bar bar-header bar-calm">
    <h1 class="title">View Title</h1>
</div>

<ion-content>

<div class="list">

  <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#">
    <i class="icon ion-email"></i>
    Check mail
  </a>

  <a class="item item-icon-left item-icon-right" href="#">
    <i class="icon ion-chatbubble-working"></i>
    Call Ma
    <i class="icon ion-ios7-telephone-outline"></i>
  </a>

  <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#">
    <i class="icon ion-mic-a"></i>
    Record album
    <span class="item-note">
      Grammy
    </span>
  </a>

  <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#">
    <i class="icon ion-person-stalker"></i>
    Friends
    <span class="badge badge-assertive">0</span>
  </a>

</div>
</ion-content>


<ion-tabs class="tabs-energized tabs-icon-top">
    <ion-tab title="Leagues" icon="ion-home" href="#"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="My Team" icon="ion-star" href="#"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: I can put the list inside of a div and add a style: <div style="margin-top:40px;"> But I don't think it is a good way for doing that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ok. I finally figured it out. Instead of using margin-top in the css style.  I just added a ionic class in ion-content tag, then the issue is gone.

`<ion-content class="has-header">`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you figured out the `<ion-content class="has-header"></ion-content>`.

Regarding your second issue with the tabs not being at the top: Ionic on iOS places the tabs at the bottom and on Android it places them on top. You can override their setting by adding this to your `appname.config()`:

```
$ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position('bottom');
```

(remember to include `$ionicConfigProvider` as one of the config dependencies).

Answer (score 3):

```
The following code would help you to resolve your second issue.    

<ion-view>        
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-calm">
        <h1 class="title">View Title</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
        <div class="list">
           ...
        </div>
    </ion-content>
    <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-top">
         <ion-tab title="Leagues" icon="ion-home" href="#"></ion-tab>
         <ion-tab title="My Team" icon="ion-star" href="#"></ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the first item in the list not showing up, make sure your code is contained within an `<ion-view>` directive, like this:

```
<ion-view>        
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-calm">
        <h1 class="title">View Title</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
        <div class="list">
           ...
        </div>
    </ion-content>
    <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top">
        <ion-tab title="Leagues" icon="ion-home" href="#"></ion-tab>
        <ion-tab title="My Team" icon="ion-star" href="#"></ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>
</ion-view>
```

As for the location of the tab bar, Ionic should automatically display it on top in an Android app and at the bottom in an iOS app. Have a look at the [Ionic documentation for tabs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#striped-style-tabs).

Answer (score 0):

if your view has the header then you must have to mention it in the ion-content i.e

```
<ion-content class='has-header'></ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add:

```
<ion-content class="has-header">
</ion-content>
```

This will display your first item.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the HEADER section on your content so use the following

```
<ion-content class="has-header">
```